# Overwriting Bootstrap 4 Navbar Link Color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Good night everyone,

I've been playing around with Bootstrap 4 and made a simple Navbar and wanted to change the font-size and the color (or hover color) but for some reason the font-size seems to work, but the color not. I also can't seem to add additional padding between each item. I thought as long as I insert the custom CSS file after the Bootstrap 4 I can simply overwrite stuff. (It's for a course I'm attending, so please don't mind the Halo Topic)

```css
main {
    color: brown;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 1200px;
}

#Wallpaper {
    height: 220px;
    width: 100%;
}

#sticky-footer {
    height: 60px;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Master Chief</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WebsiteCSS.css">
 
  </head>


<body>

<img id="Wallpaper" src="/Website/Images/HomeWallpaper.png" alt="Halo Wallpaper"> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <!-- Masterchief Logo -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/Website/Images/Logo.png" alt="Halo Logo" style="width:40px;">
  </a>
        
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Halo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Handlung</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fraktionen</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Master Chief</a>
    </li>
  <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Spielreihe
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo 3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo Wars</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo Reach</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo 4</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo 5: Guardians</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id odio reiciendis consectetur architecto cumque? Iste reprehenderit magni dicta ex iusto officia ducimus dolorum? Consequuntur esse numquam, illum sit sapiente officiis?
</main>
<footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-3 bg-dark text-white-50">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <small>Copyright &copy; Master Chief</small>
  </div>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `!important` in your CSS.

```css
main {
    color: brown;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 1200px;
}

#Wallpaper {
    height: 220px;
    width: 100%;
}

#sticky-footer {
    height: 60px;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: brown !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Master Chief</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WebsiteCSS.css">
 
  </head>


<body>

<img id="Wallpaper" src="/Website/Images/HomeWallpaper.png" alt="Halo Wallpaper"> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <!-- Masterchief Logo -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/Website/Images/Logo.png" alt="Halo Logo" style="width:40px;">
  </a>
        
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Halo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Handlung</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fraktionen</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Master Chief</a>
    </li>
  <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Spielreihe
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo 3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo Wars</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo Reach</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo 4</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Halo 5: Guardians</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id odio reiciendis consectetur architecto cumque? Iste reprehenderit magni dicta ex iusto officia ducimus dolorum? Consequuntur esse numquam, illum sit sapiente officiis?
</main>
<footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-3 bg-dark text-white-50">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <small>Copyright &copy; Master Chief</small>
  </div>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not doing anything for me

Comment: If you wanted to change the font color of the navbar links, it works, check by running my code snippet.

Comment: Im sorry, apparantly something is wrong with my localhost, even though i refresh the page it doesnt seem to do anything. It worked after a restart. Is it actually possible to use the nav-tabs to display certain things with only HTML?

Comment: Sometimes you need control+F5 to force a cache refresh, yes check the second half of the docs at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Comment: Okay i actually found out, using Private Mode solves the issue, because it appears that my regular browser saves the website in the cache and doesnt renew it till a restart. Good to know :), also ty for the link

Answer (score 0):

use inspect element *(right click the element and click inspect)* in your project. you will find where the color is applied.
[image]

selector used to apply color is shown in inspection. so copy selector path and overwrite with your style. example:

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link{
   color: brown;
}
```

Comment: Awsome i didn't know about that, that makes it kinda easy to overwrite it with CSS :)